# What possible reasons could make arbitrage impossible between some markets?

Tags: finance, efficient-markets, financial-markets

What could prevent arbitrage (not necessarily risk-free) between some markets even when price differences exist?

Answer (score 6):

The seminal paper in this area with over 3,000 citations is by Shleifer and Vishney:

> Textbook arbitrage in financial markets requires no capital and
>   entails no risk. In reality, almost all arbitrage requires capital,
>   and is typically risky. Moreover, professional arbitrage is conducted
>   by a relatively small number of highly specialized investors using
>   other people's capital. Such professional arbitrage has a number of
>   interesting implications for security pricing, including the
>   possibility that arbitrage becomes ineffective in extreme
>   circumstances, when prices diverge far from fundamental values. The
>   model also suggests where anomalies in financial markets are likely to
>   appear, and why arbitrage fails to eliminate them.

The Limits of Arbitrage ([Andrei Shleifer and Robert W. Vishny (1997)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1997.tb03807.x/full))

[There are many versions online](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=12337463257772968513&hl=en&as_sdt=0,9), one of them is likely ungated.

Answer (score -1):

There are two necessary conditions for such a price discrimination :
 1. The markets should be isolated
 2. Some sort of price making power should be involved i.e. some degree of    imperfection is required.